# how do write c/c++ code that equal this assembly code?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

MSVC, before c++11, /O1 or /O2

like
memcpy(p, "111112244551", n);

but "111112244551" is immediate value, not in 'rdata' section.

assembly code:
eax point to a heap memory region, not stack memroy

```
    mov [eax+10h], 30303030h
    mov [eax+14h], 31323334h
    mov [eax+18h], 35353535h
    mov [eax+1ch], 3334h
```

How do write c/c++ code? please

don't:

p[0] = xx; p[1] = xx; p[n] = xx ...

-

-

Additional(from IDA):

```
    mov     dword ptr [eax+10h], 41424344h
    mov     dword ptr [eax+14h], 45464748h
    mov     word ptr [eax+18h], 65h
```

I want c/c++ code.

Comment: Use `__asm__("your asm code here");`

Comment: There is no such thing as "c/c++". Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: This is assembly code, not machine code. The former is possible, the latter not so much.

Comment: What do you mean "don't `p[0] = xx; p[1] = xx; p[n] = xx ...`"?  That is how you write it in C, but with `0x30303030` instead of `h` suffix.  Some compilers would optimize the `memcpy` to immediate stores instead of an actual copy, especially if alignment was unknown or SSE was disabled.  Are you asking how to write C that will compile to that asm?  That depends entirely on your compiler.  C as a language doesn't distinguish between immediate vs. rdata, so from an abstract language perspective the question makes no sense.

Comment: `memcpy` from const data may actually turn into that expected machine code I guess... And what's wrong about `p[0]=xx;`, that's probably most straightforward asm-to-C "translation" of that code, which has highest chance to end being compiled back into similar machine code. (Ninjaed by Peter Cordes, who is even more accurate and better telling what I had on mind :) )

Answer (score 4):

> how do write c/c++ code that equal this machine code?

**In general, you cannot.**

The [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of C++11 (or of C11), as defined by their respective standard ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) for C++11, [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for C11) is of higher level than that of the x86-64 machine code (or assembler). You could ask for C++ (or C) code whose *observable behavior* is similar to the one of your assembler code (but that is a different question).

Be aware of possible [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), of [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), of [decompilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) (they address an [intractable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) or [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) problem, provable to be equivalent to the [halting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) problem), of [code obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)), and of the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule). Read also about [static source code analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), [malware analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware_analysis) and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

What you might ask (but that is a very different question) is how to make some particular compiler (the version and optimization details matter of course a big lot) generate a particular piece of code. In general there is no answer (except of course `asm` instructions, whose interpretation and semantics is not defined by the standard but by your particular compiler or C or C++ implementation).

Be aware that a programming language is a specification, not a software.

(so you are confused, and stricto sensu your question makes no sense so is unclear).

Notice that your assembler code might have been generated with something else that the compiler you believe has been used. For example, a postprocessor might "transform" the assembler code before the linker (and still keep the original C or C++ semantics).